# Receiving toast notifications on Windows Phone when app is not running

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8, mpns

My toast message has the following format:

```cs
string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
"<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
"<wp:Toast>" +
    "<wp:Text1>[string]</wp:Text1>" +
    "<wp:Text2>[string]</wp:Text2>" +
    "<wp:Param>[string]</wp:Param>" +
    "<wp:myCustomParam1>[string]</wp:myCustomParam1>" +
    "<wp:myCustomParam2>[string]</wp:myCustomParam2>" +
    "<wp:myCustomParam3>[string]</wp:myCustomParam3>" +
"</wp:Toast>" +
"</wp:Notification>";
```

While my app is running I can receive my custom parameters (wp:myCustomParam1 and other) on `ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)` event handler as keys in `e.Collection`

But when my app is not running and notification comes, the user taps on pop-up notification and app started, the ShellToastNotificationReceived doesn't calls and notification is lost.

So, how can I get my custom parameters in this case?

Comment: This question has been asked several times recently. Check my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331528/how-can-i-handle-toast-notifications-on-windows-phone-7-when-application-is-not/15561961#15561961).